# in magento controller file there is one get function is there "$mobile -> $model ->getphone();" where is that get phone method defined

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, model

in magento custom module controller file there is one get function is there for getting a phone number "$mobile -> $model ->getphone();" where is that get phone method defined.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't enough detail in this question to give a good answer, but in a more generic sense, it looks like it comes from whatever class "$model" is and could either be a concrete method defined in the "$model" class (or inherited) file, or it could be a "getter" method which actually resolves to the "__call" method. If it's a "getter" method call (which means this method will not be defined concretely anywhere) than somewhere in the "$model"s _data array it should contain the key "phone" which could be being set somewhere else, or more likely is from whatever database table "$model" is using. If you don't know which table that is you can find it in the config.xml file for the module.